# Upgrading spring transaction from 1.2.5 to 4.1.1

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions, spring-transactions

Am facing an issue while upgrading spring from 1.2.5 to 4.1.1. With the spring1.2.5 spring was committing all my changes to the dao objects in the table without an explicit update query call. But after the upgrade changes is not getting persisted automatically.

Below is my value for my hibernate.transaction.jta.platform configuration

```
<prop key="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform">org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.WeblogicJtaPlatform</prop>
```

After debugging i found in the transaction interceptor class of spring transaction jar, commitTransactionAfterReturning method is being invoked which is committing all changes in the transaction. But am not able to find a equivalent method in the transaction interceptor class of spring transaction 4.1.1 jar. I do not want do explicit updates for all the changes & I want spring to handle them as it was performing in 1.2.5 version.
Please let me know how to handle the above scenario.